# How can apply Datatable sorting on a part of column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, data-binding, datatable

I have a `DataTable`. and i want to apply sorting on a column using C# `Sort` function.
but I have multiple value into column(with separator - Æ).

So i really want to apply sorting on a specific part of a column. It is possible or not.

For Example - My `DataTable` column is `Tag`. Column `Tag` have two value - `TagId + TagName`
Now i want to apply sort only on `TagName`.

How can i do ?

Example -
My `DataTable` `dt`

> Tag
>
> 10ÆAA -------->(`TagId`Æ`TagName`)
>
> 15ÆBB -------->(`TagId`Æ`TagName`)
>
> 0ÆCC -------->(`TagId`Æ`TagName`)
>
> 20ÆGG -------->(`TagId`Æ`TagName`)

In code -

`dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Tag DESC";` // -- I try this this code but it apply sorting on whole column

I want result like this (sorted according `TagName`)

> Tag
>
> 20ÆGG
>
> 0ÆCC
>
> 15ÆBB
>
> 10ÆAA

Not like this (not sorted according `TagId`)

> Tag
>
> 0ÆCC
>
> 10ÆAA
>
> 15ÆBB
>
> 20ÆGG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace the `Tag` column with `TagId` and `TagName` columns? That would make your data structure make sense, and in turn make working with it (e.g. sorting) make sense.  If not, I think this ought to work:

```
var ordered = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(
 x => x.Field<string>("Tag").Substring(x.Field<string>("Tag").IndexOf("Æ") + 1));
```

Comment: End bracket Of OrderByDescending is missing    -   var ordered = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(
  x => x.Field<string>("Tag").Substring(x.Field<string>("Tag").IndexOf("Æ") + 1));

Answer (score 0):

If you have original columns in your `datatable` then you can use those columns for sorting.
Else you will have to loop through `data-table` each row and create a new `data-table` and use it for your code.